# Getting 'trigrams' in Java

Tags: java, analysis, n-gram, trigram

I am having a bit of an issue getting `trigrams` in Java.  My program can currently get `bigrams` fine but when I try to implement the same structure of the method and change it to get `trigrams` it seems to not work as well. 
I want the `trigrams` to get every possible combination of words within the `arraylist`, e.g.

```
Original = [eye, test, find, free, nhs]
Trigram = [eye test find, 2, eye test free, 3, eye test nhs, 4, eye find free, 3, eye find nhs, 4, eye free nhs, 5, etc...]
```

The numbers determine the distance between the first word and the last word and should get every combination of words of a 3 in the `arraylist`.  This currently works fine for `bigrams`...

```
Original = [eye, test, find, free, nhs]
Bigram = [eye test, 1, eye find, 2, eye free, 3, eye nhs, 4, test find, 1, test free, 2, test nhs, 3, find free, 1, etc..]
```

Here are the methods

```
public ArrayList<String> bagOfWords;
public ArrayList<String> bigramList = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<String> trigramList = new ArrayList<String>();


public void trigram() throws FileNotFoundException{
    PrintWriter tg = new PrintWriter(new File(trigramFile));
    // CREATES THE TRIGRAM
    for (int i = 0; i < bagOfWords.size() - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < bagOfWords.size() - 1; j++) {
            for(int k = j + 1; k < bagOfWords.size(); k++){
                int distance = (k - i);
                if (distance < 4){
                    trigramList.add(bagOfWords.get(i) + " " + bagOfWords.get(j) + " " + bagOfWords.get(k) + ", " + distance);
                }
            }
        }
    }


public void bigram() throws FileNotFoundException{
    // CREATES THE BIGRAM
    PrintWriter bg = new PrintWriter(new File(bigramFile));
    for (int i = 0; i < bagOfWords.size() - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < bagOfWords.size(); j++) {
            int distance = (j - i);
            if (distance < 4){
                bigramList.add(bagOfWords.get(i) + " " + bagOfWords.get(j) + ", " + distance);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me alter the `trigram()` method to create an appropriate `trigram` for what I need? 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `j` to start at `i+1`, don't you? Also, I think you are letting `i` count to far. It should stop at `bagOfWords.size() - 2`. I am not sure why you check `distance < 4`. This will throw out valid groups.

```
public void trigram() throws FileNotFoundException{
PrintWriter tg = new PrintWriter(new File(trigramFile));
// CREATES THE TRIGRAM
for (int i = 0; i < bagOfWords.size() - 2; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < bagOfWords.size() - 1; j++) {
        for(int k = j + 1; k < bagOfWords.size(); k++){
            int distance = (k - i);
            trigramList.add(bagOfWords.get(i) + " " + bagOfWords.get(j) + " " + bagOfWords.get(k) + ", " + distance);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer of @bradimus is exactly right. I just gonna show another approach. Did you noticed, that your methods very similar? So, why not to try merge it to one universal method? Something like following:

```
public List<String> anygram(List<String> bagOfWords, int gramCount){

     List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

     for(int i=0;i<=bagOfWords.size()-gramCount; i++){
         for(int j=i; j+gramCount<=bagOfWords.size(); j++){
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(bagOfWords.get(i));
            int k = j+1;
            for(; k<j+gramCount; k++){
                builder.append(" ");
                builder.append(bagOfWords.get(k));
            }
            builder.append(", ").append(k-i-1);
            result.add(builder.toString());
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

My answer is not for rating. I just became interested in this task, and come to this solution.

Comment: yeah I did think about doing it in the same method but when I tried that it was getting very laggy and glitchy due to the amount  of data it was processing so I decided just to keep it all separate! May try amalgamating it though

Comment: I think it was laggy because you used directly string concatenation. When you process compose big amount of strings, it always better to use `StringBuilder`,  because it improves performance.